# Grails - How to avoid rollback after stop app

Tags: postgresql, grails, jdbc

I have my app in grails ... when i run-app , works fine i can create , modify and delete record but when i stop the app the data in the tables seems to be rolled back

Could be some steps to follow to avoid that behaviour?

**BuildConfig.groovy**

```
    dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.

    // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.16'
    runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1207.jre7'
}

plugins {
    runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
    runtime ":jquery:1.7.1"
    runtime ":resources:1.1.6"
```

**Datasource.groovy**

```
dataSource {
pooled = true
driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
username = "****"
password = "*****"
}
hibernate {
cache.use_second_level_cache = true
cache.use_query_cache = false
cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
development {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
        url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Prizy_Pricer"
    }
}
test {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Prizy_Pricer"
    }
}
production {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Prizy_Pricer"
        pooled = true
        properties {
           maxActive = -1
           minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
           timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
           numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
           testOnBorrow=true
           testWhileIdle=true
           testOnReturn=true
           validationQuery="SELECT 1"
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default environment for the command `grails run-app` is *development*. Although you have a PostgreSQL database configured for the *development* environment, the `dbCreate` property is set to *create-drop*, which means drop all of the tables and then re-create them. So, of course, dropping the tables deletes all of the data. Here are the possible settings for `dbCreate`:

- **create** - Drops the existing schema and creates the schema on startup, dropping existing tables, indexes, etc. first.
- **create-drop** - Same as create, but also drops the tables when the application shuts down cleanly.
- **update** - Creates missing tables and indexes, and updates the current schema without dropping any tables or data. Note that this can't properly handle many schema changes like column renames (you're left with the old column containing the existing data).
- **validate** - Makes no changes to your database. Compares the configuration with the existing database schema and reports warnings. any other value - does nothing

What you probably want is to change the `dbCreate` setting to *update* for your development environment.

### An even better approach, I think

I prefer to leave the *development* with the default in-memory database and just populate it in **BootStrap.groovy**. That way, the database can be safely thrown away at any moment. For an example of how to do this, see [this](https://bitbucket.org/erosa/gormtut/src/508535438095d31f854613d127806935dd6e6c35/grails-app/init/BootStrap.groovy?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default).

Comment: I will never understand why someone would mark an answer correct, without upticking it.  +1 to compensate.